# switching pages base from $_GET['year'] without creating multiple files

Tags: php

i have a drop down year button, which switches from 2011, 2012, 2013. my problem is how to display the specific quarter for the selected year without creating multiple files? example quarter 1(january, february, march) of year 2011 contains data and other values that the user input, but quarter 1 of year 2012 doesnt contain anything. so if i switch to year 2012, quarter 1 still displays but without values since it has no values in the first place. how will do that kind of switching?

here is my code

```
<?php    
     if(isset($_GET['year'])){
        $getyear=$_GET['year'];
     } else {
        $getyear=date("Y");
     }
?>
```

for the fetching of sql data:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE month='$monthnow' AND type = 'Consumer' 
      AND year = '$getyear' AND category='$categid')
```

please disregard the other data, my only problem is on the year part.

Comment: $quarter=1; if(isset($_GET['quarter'])) $quarter=intval($_GET['quarter']);

Comment: on which part will i integrate that? i dont get what your code would do sorry. -_- i can switch from quarter to quarter but not quarter to year.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` - it's deprecated and vulnerable to sql injection. Use  either `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Comment: @alfasin its okay though. its an intranet designed system only. no worries. :D

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you please explain it a bit better?
Consider adding an example.

Comment: add the quarter code below your year code, and next to the year selector create a quarter selector too. AND add date BETWEEN to your query. ie BETWEEN 2011-01 AND 2011-03 for quarter 1 2011

Comment: example

2011
1Quarter
January= ofir
february = " "
march = baruch

Lets say for the year 2012, 1st quarter does not contain anything and when i click the 2012 link it would display:

2012
1Quarter

January = " "
February = " "
March = " "

without creating multiple files. just changing the contents of the quarters itself.